# Range.Address property does not work properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have an R1C1 formula, which consists of IF and VLOOKUP functions and few variables:

```
Sub example()

    Set vlpRange = wsRef.Range("B:E")

    '[some code...]

    newColumn.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(MID(RC[-17],14,3)=""LCO""," _
    & """LCO"",VLOOKUP(RC[-10],'[" & wbRef.Name & "]" & _
    wsRef.Name & "'!" & vlpRange.Address(0, 0) & "," & vlpColIndex & ",0))"

    '[some code...]

End Sub
```

I get the following result in each cell:

`=IF(MID(F2,14,3)="LCO","LCO",VLOOKUP(M2,'[SPS Product groups.xlsx]Sheet1'!B:(E),4,0))`

The problem is in `vlpRange.Address(0, 0)`, which being converted into `B:(E)`, instead of `B:E`.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: My guess as to why, you are trying to use a specific address in a R1C1 formula, hence the reason the answer below works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to swap

```
vlpRange.Address(0, 0)
```

for

```
vlpRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped, but I got `$B:$E`. I still cannot understand why does this happen.

Comment: Yes, I tried it couple of times as well and all other uses of vlpRange.Address(0, 0) return normal B:E, which is quite strange. If you dont mind the fixed columns the replacement might help you, but I will try to find something better when I have a minute...

Comment: So after couple of tries I believe that Scott is correct (in comment to your original question). I was able to get abolute reference $B:$E several times, but every time I try without absolute reference you either get "B:(E)" or you have to reference it to some point and risk getting different columns and it is not possible to just put in normal "B:E" value. When I was putting the formula to column G I got the "B:E" without $ signs using vlpRange.Address(0, 0, xlR1C1, RelativeTo:=Range("G:G")).